# $('body').click('li', func) Vs $('li').click(func), Second option does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

```
$('body').click('li', function(){
  console.log('clicked - handler 1')
})
$('li').click(function(){
  console.log("clicked - handler 2")
})
```

I am adding two handlers to `li element`'s click event using two different selector mechanisms. When i click the element,
the console log says,

```
clicked - handler 1
```

This means, the second handler is not added at all. What is wrong with selecting `li element` directly instead of selecting `body and then li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option may not work in one of the cases:

1. "li" elements are added dynamically to the page, and not on page load (in other words, when selector is executed, there are no matching elements at that time).
2. The code you posted is executed before DOM is fully loaded (eg., placed in simple `<script>` tag).

If it's the second, try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('li').click(function(){
     console.log("clicked - handler 2")
   })
});
```

This code will be executed after DOM is loaded, and thus $('li') selector will succeed.

The first option works because "body" DOM element is available early thus you successfully attach event handlers to it (second selector only acts as a filter for event target, but actual handler is attached to "body").

Comment: thanks man... this operator in both the handlers, does it refer to `li` element (or) it is the `body` element?

Comment: Use console.log() and check it yourself :)